# Jupyter throws error 'OMC Server is down..' when running code using OpenModelica's OMPython

Tags: python, jupyter, openmodelica

The error is attached. 
I opened the file from the given location in Temp folder, it just contains the text 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.'
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
- OMPython - ERROR - OMC Server is down. Please start it! Log-file says:
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2758f53a36c2> in <module>
----> 1 tank = ModelicaSystem('WaterTank.mo', 'WaterTank.ModWaterTank')
      2 q = tank.getQuantities()
      3 # print('Type of q: ', type(q))
      4 type(q)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OMPython\__init__.py in __init__(self, fileName, modelName, lmodel, useCorba)
    679             self.getconn = OMCSession()
    680         else:
--> 681             self.getconn = OMCSessionZMQ()
    682         self.xmlFile = None
    683         self.lmodel = lmodel  # may be needed if model is derived from other model

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OMPython\__init__.py in __init__(self, readonly, timeout)
    539         self._start_omc_process()
    540         # connect to the running omc instance using CORBA
--> 541         self._connect_to_omc(timeout)
    542 
    543     def __del__(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OMPython\__init__.py in _connect_to_omc(self, timeout)
    562                     self._omc_log_file.close()
    563                     logger.error("OMC Server is down. Please start it! Log-file says:\n%s" % open(name).read())
--> 564                     raise Exception("OMC Server is down. Could not open file %s" % self._port_file)
    565                 else:
    566                     continue

Exception: OMC Server is down. Could not open file C:/Users/RADICA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/openmodelica.port.7c438238bc7b4cbc89e2f7d57ab2e010
```

Comment: Hm, I guess we need to fix OMPython to handle OpenModelica in "Program Files". For now you could install OpenModelica in a path without spaces, such as C:\OpenModelica.

Comment: Thank you @AdrianPop, this worked. It still shows the same error in Jupyter, but ompython's working in cmd. I guess I'll have to uninstall & reinstall in anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using an older OMPython, for me it works (even when OpenModelica in installed in Program Files):

```
E:\bin\py64>python -m pip install -U https://github.com/OpenModelica/OMPython/archive/master.zip
Collecting https://github.com/OpenModelica/OMPython/archive/master.zip
  Downloading https://github.com/OpenModelica/OMPython/archive/master.zip
     - 34 kB 353 kB/s
Collecting future
  Downloading future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 829 kB 1.1 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyparsing in e:\bin\py64\lib\site-packages (from OMPython==3.1.2) (2.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy in e:\bin\py64\lib\site-packages (from OMPython==3.1.2) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyzmq in e:\bin\py64\lib\site-packages (from OMPython==3.1.2) (18.1.1)
Installing collected packages: future, OMPython
    Running setup.py install for future ... done
    Running setup.py install for OMPython ... done
Successfully installed OMPython-3.1.2 future-0.18.2
```

Then I'm using OMPython:

```
E:\bin\py64>python.exe
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import OMPython
>>> from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ
>>> omc = OMCSessionZMQ()
2020-05-21 21:35:58,502 - OMPython - INFO - OMC Server is up and running at file:///C:/Users/adrpo33/AppData/Local/Temp/openmodelica.port.f995e0c74c4b4a7d900ef7442d798b89 pid=20112
>>> model_path=omc.sendExpression("getInstallationDirectoryPath()") + "/share/doc/omc/testmodels/"
>>> print(model_path)
E:/Program Files/OpenModelica1.14.0-64bit//share/doc/omc/testmodels/
>>> from OMPython import ModelicaSystem
>>> mod=ModelicaSystem(model_path + "BouncingBall.mo","BouncingBall")
2020-05-21 21:39:09,024 - OMPython - INFO - OMC Server is up and running at file:///C:/Users/adrpo33/AppData/Local/Temp/openmodelica.port.b631a8f8a6fe4e238c7dca8398fa429d pid=30128
>>> mod.getParameters()
{'e': '0.7', 'g': '9.810000000000001'}
>>> ^Z
```

You could try updating your OMPython via the first command above (using pip).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, working with OMPython_1.18 on Windows:
"OMPython - ERROR - OMC Server is down. Please start it! Log-file says:
Der Befehl "C:\Program" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden."

This is because of the blank in the path "C:\Program Files".

I added the quotes in the Python37\lib\site-packages\OMPython_*init*_.py file like:
self.omhome = """+omc_env_home+"""

And it works for me.